# pausing game in dead space 3

Tags: dead-space-3

Is there any way that I can pause dead space 3 while checking the inventory (by TAB ).
  It is very annoying that the game keeps running in background while reading text logs or mission descriptions 
 And it is also dangerous as you may be attacked by an enemy with inventory description on your face

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to check inventory and pause game at the same time. It is suppose to add to the horror element of the game.

**Single-Player**

I would clear the room (killing all the enemies) before using the inventory. I wouldn't really worry about it since the only time you need to manage the inventory is when you want to pick something up or craft more health packs.

Since in either of these circumstances you wouldn't require a pause button I wouldn't worry about it.

It is best to manage inventory also at places where you can store your items (crafting spots) instead of dropping them because they are valuable for the most part.

Ammo drops for the weapon you are currently using, so you don't need to really worry about having junk ammo in your inventory unless you changed weapons and didn't put ammo in safe that you can't currently use.

**Multi-Player**

In multi-player you can actually trade items with your partner which is helpful if he or you have extra health packs/ammo needed.

Sources:

http://www.computerandvideogames.com/181756/no-pause-option-for-dead-space/